# Hardware-Questions: Do they belong on Server Fault or on Super User?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [Same Interface routing with ICMP-Redirect disabled?](https://serverfault.com/questions/966655/same-interface-routing-with-icmp-redirect-disabled)

How do you decide whether a post should be posted to Server Fault or Super User if it doesn't fit 100% on either side? I asked what a router would do if a specific feature was disabled and if there was a specification for it.

Personally, I chose Server Fault because dedicated routers are much rarer in the private environment than in the business environment - most have a device in the private environment that is both a router and a modem - mostly simply called an "Internet router"; that they have different specifications than classic routers is clear to anyone who is familiar with the matter.

**Edit:**
I know that there are already some answers here that support my decision (e.g. question 1363) - but still my question for an accepted answer will be voted down and reported as Off-Topic. This makes me pretty insecure on this point. I would like to have this question clarified, because this downvote attitude is a great deterrent to me as a new user, especially if you don't even really know why.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question about routing hardware at all, rather about protocols and proper behavior of a router.

Comment: @Michael Hampton So you want to say that proper behavior of mainly business hardware is no topic for SF? Why do you think so?

Comment: I'm saying that the question you linked to is not about hardware.

Answer (score 4):

I closed the question mainly because it was highly theoretical: "what would happen if this other thing happened?"  If there was a specific situation where you had a need to turn redirects off, then it would make more sense to ask here about how to do it, or the consequences.

Comment: What would be the right side in your opinion to post that question? I know about SF and SU for hardware-related questions.

Comment: This isn't a "hardware related question", because you're not referring to any specific hardware.  "What should I have for dinner?" doesn't become an automotive question just because you'd drive the car to the shops.

Comment: So - Server Fault is for questions about specific hardware instead of the behaviour of the hardware because most of the people on this Q&A site are to silly to understand, that a router is hardware. Got it. Do whatever you want, but noone could even closely answer why it should be offtopic. You say its not hardware relevant, while it is. Get into the manner, then this site would become good again.

Comment: The site has no chance at all of ever becoming good again.

Comment: @Runamaus Its not hardware related at all, as all business class router support icmp redirect. Home SOHO router no. The behaviour, on how something work can be easilly be find, like the link I left you on the question, but did you took the time to read it ? You mistook a important point, you didnt stated that because of that feature you have a problem X to solve.  You actually ask for opinion on how the thing work to argument a verbal battle with your friend, while I could answer you anything, as you can’t validate the input I would tell as you have no gear to do the test.